# How to process device messages in an Edge module and sending it upstream while retaining its source and without setting message properties?

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I am trying to "transparently" intercept and modify incoming device messages. Say for example three devices send data to the Edge Hub at 20 messages per second each, I want to apply a moving average to this data and then send it upstream at a rate of 1 message per second each, while retaining the original sender information visible from the Hub and without using message properties or something alike that would require further configuration on the hub data entrypoints.

I would like to do this in a mostly transparent fashion, as if the device itself was directly connected to the IoT Hub, while retaining the Modules sinks and outputs so that multiple modules of this kind can be easily stacked merely by adapting the routes. By example linking default input to module1 sink, module1 output to module2 sink and finally module2 output to upstream.

How can this be achieved? Preferably using the Node SDK's.

Comment: Did you consider using [Azure Stream Analytics as an IoT Edge module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-deploy-stream-analytics) ? The Stream Analytics module can calculate the average over a rolling window and send it up to IoTHub as 1 message only.

Comment: This does not fit the use case, that was merely an example. The idea is that the modules do whatever transform or operation they have to, while passing it to azure as if no transformation had happened and the data came directly from a device.